# track uploadBytesResumable state_changed with React useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to asynchronously upload multiple files to google storage and show the file upload progress in the UI.

I haven't been able to reason with the combination of the `uploadBytesResumable` api by firebase/storage and reacts use state. I seem to always be updating state with a reference to an old version of state or the ordering of the files will over write state incorrectly etc.

Here is a skeleton component to give you an idea of what i'm working with and some types to guide what I mean by track the progress of upload.

```js
type FilesStatus = {
  [uuid: string]: UploadTaskSnapshot
}
export const useFileUpload = () => {
  const [filesStatus, setFilesStatus] = React.useState<FilesStatus>({})

  const uploadFiles = async (files: File[]) => {
    for (const file of files) {
      // Update state to track all file changes
      const onChange = () => {}
      const onError = () => {}
      const onComplete = () => {}

      const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`)
      uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, { contentType: file.type }).on(
        'state_changed',
        onChange,
        onError,
        onComplete,
      )
    }
  }

  return { filesStatus, uploadFiles }
}
```

Comment: turns out if you put this much effort in asking chatgpt.. you'll find your answer.
const onChange = (snapshot: UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
    setFilesStatus((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [file.name]: snapshot }))
}

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and like usual I always find a way of finding the solution as soon as I ask for help:

```js
type FilesStatus = {
  [uuid: string]: UploadTaskSnapshot | null | StorageError
}

export const useFileUpload = () => {
  const [filesStatus, setFilesStatus] = React.useState<FilesStatus>({})

  const uploadFiles = async (files: File[]) => {
    for (const file of files) {
      const uuid = uuidv4()
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${uuid}`)
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, { contentType: file.type })

      // Update state to track all file changes
      const onChange = (snapshot: UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
        setFilesStatus((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [uuid]: snapshot }))
      }
      const onError = (error: StorageError) => {
        setFilesStatus((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [uuid]: error }))
      }
      const onComplete = () => {
        setFilesStatus((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [uuid]: null }))
      }

      uploadTask.on('state_changed', onChange, onError, onComplete)
    }
  }

  return { uploadFiles, filesStatus }
}
```

It was the callback version of updating state that I was after. Consider this a public rubber duckie conversation.